# Back4App uploads a small sized file but throws error: unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile

Tags: java, android, back4app

Whenever I try to upload a file with a high speed internet connection, it uploads, but with a slightly slower internet connection (i.e., 20-30kbps), it’s not uploading anything and gives the error: "unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile blah, blah, blah. Here is my arsenal:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 17 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),selectedImage);
            Log.i("AppInfo","Images Recieved !");
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,80,byteArrayOutputStream);

            byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("photo.png",bytes);
            ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("images");
            parseObject.put("username",ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

            parseObject.put("image",parseFile);

            parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        alert("Uploaded","Image Uploaded Successfully !");
                    }else{
                        alert("Failed","Failed because "+e.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
            });

        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            alert("Failed","Failed because "+ioe.getMessage().toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Looking forward for feedback you guys!

Comment: And also am not getting the proper file name in my back4app data browser class, it read as "e.png" instead of as i coded as "image.png", why and how?

Comment: Yeah brother! Already seen them! Asked this question because am tired of looking.

Comment: Seems no one interested in helping me 

Comment: Hi, just checking, when you upload the file changing the speed connection, are they the same size file? If not, what is the size?